# "Member for" display calculation

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, algorithm

I noticed that I recently rolled over to "12 months" on my [user profile on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1185/rob) and noticed that I also did not get awarded the yearling badge. I have since figured out that it appears that you need to have "1 year" on [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1) before getting said badge. As such, I'm wondering exactly how the "Member for" fields are being calculated, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that it's doing `datediff(month, join_date, getdate())`, which rounds up in SQL Server.

In this case, you joined 8/13/08. You're two days away from the actual year mark.

```
datediff(month, '8/13/08', '8/11/09')
```

Returns 12 in SQL Server, hence, the months in your profile.

Comment: **Screw Oracle!**

Comment: Don't think so, as I joined '8/30/08' and still get 11 months.

Comment: @Ralph: You joined 9/3/08. You should get 11 months :)

Comment: Why is it then that the sandbox gives me 8/30/08 as my user creation date?

Comment: I'm using http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/ with select FROM_UNIXTIME(CreationDate) from users where Id=3724 and get '2008-08-30 10:32:31'

Answer (score 1):

Curious though, in the examples here that the same *date* in the PAST is shown as 12 months for one user, and 1 year for another. These two users were [recently awarded Yearling](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/13/yearling).

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1253052333072175600.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1253052333072175600.png)

and

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1253052353030720900.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1253052353030720900.png)

Given that the date awarded was Sep 15 2009, and both registered at some point on the 14th of the year previous, how could the calculation give different results?