# How to know "exact date of account creation" on StackOverflow?

Tags: user-accounts, dates, support

Simple as that, is there any way or hidden feature to know the exact date when I created my account on StackOverflow?

The profile page simply tells *months* which is pretty vague since there can be +/- 30 days in that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hover the mouse cursor over the estimate and you'll see a tooltip text pop up with exact date and time. This also works with other timestamps throughout the site.

This feature of getting detailed information through tooltip text is implemented throughout the site.

#### Related questions

- [Tool-tip timestamp shows a `Z`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15986/tool-tip-timestamp-shows-a-z)
- [“Member for” display calculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13674/member-for-display-calculation)

Comment: Ohh, thanks a million. That was so easy. It opened a whole new dimension for getting *timestamp* about things on SO :)