# Exact Registration Date

Tags: support, stack-overflow, dates, sign-up

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know “exact date of account creation” on StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63336/how-to-know-exact-date-of-account-creation-on-stackoverflow)

In the user;s profile, the member date part, we can see only how many months that I have been registered in *Stack Overflow*.

Is there any way to learn exactly what my register date was?

[image: User Snapshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the tooltip of the words `9 months`.

Comment: Wow.. In 9 months, i never seen this property. Thanks.

Comment: Almost all timestamps in StackExchange sites have tooltips.